# React native network connection does work in Android but not on IOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

When I run my app with network requests on android it works perfectly. But when i run it on ios i get this error instantly:

> An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.

The url is like: `https://api.site.com/v1/foo/bar`

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure you're making HTTPS request and not HTTP ?

Comment: Yes. It says https in the url.

Comment: are using fetch could you should the code

Comment: Is your destination URL has valid certification for SSL?

Comment: Yes it has a valid ssl certificate

Answer (score 0):

If you have a self-signed certificate, it will show up as an invalid certificate in iOS.

Depending on your networking, you might want to try pinning the certificate or allow invalid certificates (Alamofire has a security policy option for this e.g.). You can do this manually as well.

You can also easily debug issues if you open the API URL in Safari and check if it shows valid certificate as expected.